# Deep Link and Stripe redirect

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments, react-navigation

So I am trying to redirect my react-native application from a stripe checkout page back to the application.

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const prices = await stripe.prices.list({
    lookup_keys: [req.body.lookup_key],
    expand: ['data.product'],
  });
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    billing_address_collection: 'auto',
    line_items: [
      {
        price: prices.data[0].id,
        // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
        quantity: 1,

      },
    ],
    mode: 'subscription',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/?success=true&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?canceled=true`,
  });

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});
```

using the success URL but it won't redirect back into the application.
I'm currently using React Navigation, Deep Linking in the App.js file.

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: [ Linking.createURL("hometrack://")],
  config:{
    screens:{
      EmployeeSignUp:{
        path:"EmployeeSignUp/:id",
        parse: {
          id: (id) => `${id}`,
        },
      },
      Success:{
        path:"Success"
      }
      
    }
  }
};
```

I can't seem to make it link back into the application.

Comment: This is more a Stripe question than React! Which version of the API are you using? Have you verified your domain in the dashboard to receive redirects?

Comment: @cuuupid I believe so, it works when I put a localhost URL but not with the deep link in react-navigation.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to the app using the deep link/custom URL scheme? If so, does your deep link work normally, i.e. if you were to go to `hometrack://...some url...`?

Comment: @cuuupid when i use this command  ```npx uri-scheme open "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/hometrack://EmployeeSignUp/6264385f19b66c695f651a63" --ios``` it opens to the page im looking for.

Comment: Why not use the Stripe React Native SDK?

Comment: @abe did not know it existed, thank you I'll look into it.

Comment: Have you assigned a value to `YOUR_DOMAIN`? Is it your intention to omit URL's path when you construct `success_url` and `cancel_url`. Also note the absence of `/` after the host part of URL.

Comment: @Abe correct me if I am wrong but I don't believe the [Stripe React Native SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries/react-native) covers this scenario

Comment: @HBCondo this is for a payment sheet but it may work in a similar way for other components - https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#react-native-set-up-return-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deep link with custom URL scheme (myapp://screen..) does not work in this case. Stripe expects a valid URL that redirects to a real website. I am currently facing the same problem, and my workaround is:

- Redirect the user to my website (e.g. myapp.com/redirect).
- Display the "Redirect back to app" button on the website.
- Deep link back to the app

I'll update my answer if I will find another solution.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of had to do the same thing.

Comment: Wanted to follow-up and see if anyone had an update on this. [Stripe still requires a HTTP/HTTPS redirect link](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#common-examples). So after redirecting the user to my HTTPS website, I have the website return a 301 redirect with the deep link. The app then closes the browser and returns the user back to the app w/o having to click a button.

Comment: How do you get the deep link working? where do you find the "myapp" part of the myapp:// url

Comment: Hey did you find any solutions to resolve it ?